# javascript - jquery Object Key Pair is Undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, object

I am iterating through html element which is input field by using jquery, but I get error. Here is my code:

```
$(".submit_button").on("click touch", function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    var formdata = {};

    $(this).closest("div")
        .find("[data-field]")
        .each(function(i, val){
            var field = $(this).attr("data-field");             
            if($(this).is("[data-group]")) {
                var group = $(this).attr("data-role");
                formdata[group][field] = $(this).val() || "";
            } else {
                formdata[field] = $(this).val() || "";
            }
        });
    alert(JSON.stringify(formdata));
    return;
});
```

When I click submit button, the error console in firebug said that:

`formdata[group] is undefined`

How should it be written, so it is run correctly?

Comment: @Saty no I think it's OK as an object (`{}`). It's not really being used as a JavaScript array.

Answer (score 1):

You have to define formdata[group]. Test this:

```
$(".submit_button").on("click touch", function(e){
e.preventDefault();

var formdata = {};

$(this).closest("div")
    .find("[data-field]")
    .each(function(i, val){
        var field = $(this).attr("data-field");             
        if($(this).is("[data-group]")) {
            var group = $(this).attr("data-role");
            if(!(group in formdata)){ //if group is not present in formdata, define it
               formdata[group] = {}; 
            }
            formdata[group][field] = $(this).val() || "";
        } else {
            formdata[field] = $(this).val() || "";
        }
    });
    alert(JSON.stringify(formdata));
    return;
});
```